# Question about meaning of "pull a few late-nighters" and "gainfully employed" in this text

Tags: sentence-meaning

> First and foremost, I am a mother to a beautiful soul, who is my entire universe. If children aren't your thing, please don't waste your time reading any further. I want to end up with someone who sees her as the best part of me, because that is exactly what she is. FYI: her father and I maintain a brilliant co-parenting relationship.
>
> I am loyal, intelligent, spontaneous, sassy, classy and a bit smart-assy. I love to travel, and most of the time I have my trips planned out 6-12 months in advance. But I can also be persuaded to fly by the seat of my pants and pack up to go on a whim.
>
> I am **gainfully employed** and enjoy what I do quite a bit. Not much work-related traveling these days, however,  I'm known **to pull a few late-nighters** occasionally.

When she says that she was gainfully employed, what does she mean by that? According to google, it has to do with getting work and payment consistantly. And this makes me more confused. Does she mean that there are always work for her? That she is not going to become between jobs or domething?

My second concern has to do with **pulling out few late nighters** . In my opinion and based on my perception late-nighter is the guy that sleeps late at nights but when they say **pulling them out** then it is not a clear statement.

Comment: Note that they say *pull*, not *pull out*. A related common idiom [pull an all-nighter](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/pull_an_all-nighter) has its own entry in Wiktionary: "Work diligently throughout the night."

Answer (score 2):

> gainfully employed

This means that the subject has a vocation that allows for a reasonably comfortable lifestyle.

> pull a few late-nighters

This is an informal term that means the subject is willing to work late on projects when required.

Answer (score 0):

The main meaning of “she is employed” means “she has a (paid) job”.

However, there is a broader meaning, being “to be occupied or engaged with [an activity]”.  For example:

All three of them were fully employed grabbing bits of pipe and trying to fit them together, and so failed to notice that everyone else had moved on to the next stage.

It is this latter meaning that the expression “gainfully employed” invokes; it strongly suggests that she has a *paid* job, but what it actually means is that she does not sit around doing nothing.

The other use of “gainfully employed” is when someone is *not* paid, but is doing something worthwhile with their time, such as a retired person doing volunteer work 25 hours/week.  That is not what is meant here; here, it is an indirect way of saying that she has a proper job.

As PaulProgrammer, above, notes… if you say, “I am gainfully employed.”, and smile broadly, it means that you have a job that is (very) well-paid, and are being modest.  I would take the quoted instance that way.